Parameter uncertainty in curve fitting
My real problem has a much more complexity and a different function than following. However, for the sake of simplicity assume I have a data that can be described as a one dimensional Gaussian function:
$$y = Ae\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma}\right)$$
The $x$ variable which is the input to this Gaussian function is not an independent variable, rather $x$ values could be time for example. The output of the function is only the intensity of a signal.
After I fit my Gaussian function to my data I will have three fitted parameters $A$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$.
If the problem was regression, that is having an independent variable $x$ and the dependent variable $y$, then I would use the covariance matrix.
However, in this case of curve fitting, $x$ is not an independent variable.
How can I estimate the uncertainty in the model fits?
Some references to learn about uncertainty in curve fitting is also appreciated.

Could you clarify the definition of independent variable you're using here and indicate which aspect of that definition your x-variable doesn't satisfy? It may be important that we're all on the same page with this.

OP I think your question about optimisation is better suited to the operations research site.
curve fitting does not require random variables.

you define an objective function
you find a (local?) minimum (where the gradient (of objective function wrt parameters) is zero
the "uncertainty" in the parameter estimates is related to the second derivative: the greater the curvature, the more sensitive the objective function is to the parameter and the more "certainty" you have

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization
and see eg https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares, for least squares objective function
